# Swift pass block as parameter

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, closures

I have the following function calling Parse written i swift:

```
func listCatalogItemsWithBlock(completion: (result: ([ParseCatalog], NSError)) -> Void)
    {
        let parseClassName = ParseCatalog.parseClassName()
        let query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (ParseCatalog catalog, NSError error) -> Void in

        }
    }
```

What i want is to forward the result block of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` to `listCatalogItemsWithBlock` function's block, so i can process the results elsewhere.

How can i do that?

UPDATE 1

I have managed to do this quite easily:

```
 func listCatalogItemsWithBlock(completion: PFQueryArrayResultBlock)
    {
        let parseClassName = ParseCatalog.parseClassName()
        let query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(completion)
    }
```

But in this case i passed a PFQueryArrayResultBlock type. Which is:

`public typealias PFQueryArrayResultBlock = ([PFObject]?, NSError?) -> Void`

How do i return the same results if i keep my function the original way:

```
func listCatalogItemsWithCompletion(completion:([ParseCatalog]?, NSError?) -> Void)
 /* What goes here? */
}
```

Update 2
Like this:

```
func listCatalogItemsWithCompletion(completion:(fvResponse: [ParseCatalog], fvError: NSError?) -> Void)
{
    let parseClassName = ParseCatalog.parseClassName()
    let query = PFQuery(className: parseClassName)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (response:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        completion(fvResponse: response as! [ParseCatalog], fvError: error)
    }        
}
```

Comment: Uh do what you want with response inside the success block of this method? You are already inside block of list method. On success you can forward the response array to whatever other place you want to process it in.

Comment: Also keep in mind findObjectsInBackground will send you array of all objects found. Not a `ParseCatalog` object.

Comment: @NSNoob: True, i updated the question. I do not necessarily want to enter the block, only in objc you are still able to call the block using completion(catalog, error) in the end. Any solution is fine. As i said  i want to forward the result block so i can process it somewhere else in my code. I only started swift recently and still have problems with the syntax.

Comment: Do you want to forward it to some other function in your current Viewcontroller file?

Comment: In the success block of this method you can call your other method, pass the response array as a parameter to it. Again, the query will give you an array of all matching result objects! Not a ParseCatalog object

Comment: I manged to do this by waiting for the same type of block that parse returns. I updated my question as well. Can You please tell me how to pass the results if keep the original function? Also thank you very much for your kind help already.

Comment: So right now i only have one problem left: The result is ([PFObject]?, NSError?) -> Void, but what i need is ([ParseCatalog]?, NSError?) -> Void.
ParseCatalog is a subclass of PFObject. So i would only need to mark that it's loading lazily to the compiler.